# How to randomly assign value to textbox onload

Tags: jquery, arrays, random, onload

Onload page values are assign perfectly to textbox from array but i need to randomly assign values from array to text box.Please suggest some ideas
Code link

Comment: Try [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure if what you want exactly, but this is a proposition : 
http://jsfiddle.net/BGQN5/

Steps :
1) Select n Number of Inputs
2) Select n Random dates
3) Shuffle dates
4) Assign Values to array.

```
$(function(){
  var i = prompt('Number of input ? ');
  for(var j=0;j<i;j++)
  {
  add();
  }
  var test = new Array(i);
  for(var j=0;j<i;j++)
  {
  test[j] = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date());
  }
  test =shuffle(test);
   for(var j=0;j<i;j++)
  {
  var d = test[j];
  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

  $("#datePicker"+(j+1)).val(curr_month+'/'+curr_date+'/'+curr_year);
  }
  console.log(test);
});
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length
    , temporaryValue
    , randomIndex
    ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
}
$("#datePicker0").kendoDatePicker({
    close: function () {
        console.log("closed datePicker");
    }
});

function add() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    console.log();
    cell1.innerHTML = '<input id="datePicker' + $(row).index() + '" /></td>';
    initDatePicker($(row).index());

}

function initDatePicker(c) {
    $('#datePicker' + c).kendoDatePicker({
        close: function () {
            console.log("closed datePicker");
        }
    });
}
```

Cheers